# I wish you well

Tags: idioms

> I wish you well.

'well' is an 'adverb'. How the sentence above is acceptable in English? I think 'I wish you (a) well-being(ness). or I wish you your well-being.' is grammartically correct.

Answer (score 2):

"Well" has many meanings, and in this idiom (and it is an idiom) it is not functioning as an adverb.

> I wish you well.

means "I hope that you will be well" or "I wish that good things will happen to you". It is most often said as part of a farewell.

As an idiom, one cannot properly determine the overall meaning or function by analyzing the individual words. Still, as [this definition from the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/well) points out, "well" can be used as an adjective in such constructions as

> - He is looking well.
> - I hope you get well soon.
> - I am going to be well in six months.

In "I wish you well" the word "well" could be thought of as an adverb modifying "wish" or as an adjective modifying "you". In any case the sentence is a very common one, ad is quite natural. This is  case where usage trumps rules.

Your suggested alternative

> I wish you your well-being

seems odd, I don't think I have ever heard or read it. Somewhat more probable would be:

> I wish that you retain your well-being.

But I think that sounds stilted. The suggested alternative:

> I wish you well-beingness.

is simply incorrect. There is no such word as "well-beingness" and if there were , it would not be used in this way.